# CSS loaded but not applied

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I repeat, but I couldn't find the answer. This is my website: http://www.stolems.com/pl

My problem is that files css loaded but doesn't applied. I tried in FF, Chrome, Safari and still nothing. But when I load style in tag style it works. What can I do? I noticed that my files css are mime type text/html it should be text/css?

Besides I loaded at this site admin dashboard and template. Admin dashboard works, template not..

Comment: which is ur css file ?

Comment: how you are adding css on page???

Comment: My css file is style.css, but it doesn't load all styles. Yes I added all styles as you can see. What I noticed now.. if I load for example bootstrap style from CDN it works..

Comment: What is the ressource type of your CSS file when loaded ? (ressource, not mime)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your server is serving `.css` files with **MIME** type `text/html`. It should be `text/css`. Just tell your server administrator and they will fix it for you.

If you see the console in chrome, it says:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type `text/html`.

And in firefox:

> The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, `"text/html"`, is not `"text/css"`.

This happened for your `.js` files too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a .htaccess and you have rewriteRules inside the .htaccess then take a good look if you did not forgot to notify the end of the string using a $, if you forget to notify the end of  a string most of the mime types get fuzzled up.